# Given string representation of int, check overflow

Tags: java, integer

Given the `String` representation of an `int`, I want to check for overflow.

I know how to convert a `String` from `int` using java's built in functions like `parseInt`.
But what if the `String` is so large that it might not fit into an `int`?

```
String str = "214748364781";
int res = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

I tried to check the sign of the `String` representation, do `parseInt` and if the signs don't match then I can say that it does overflow since `int` wraps around but when I actually ran it it threw a `NumberFormat` exception.

`NumberFormat` is thrown for any bad formatted string so it's not a guarantee for overflow.

So I can check that the input string's format is correct (all numbers) and then do `parseInt` then if I get `NumberFormat` I can conclude that the error's due to overflow.

However, I feel like there should be a shorter way of doing this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a different option, if all you want to do is check if your string will not overflow you could compare lexicographically. String comparison is generally much faster than parsing to a number.

Assuming only positive integers.

```
    String number = "2147483649";
    String int_max = "2147483647";

    if (number.length() > int_max.length())
    {
        System.out.println("OVERFLOW");
    }
    else if (number.length() == int_max.length()){
        int comparison = number.compareTo(int_max);
        System.out.println(comparison > 0 ? "OVERFLOW" : "");
    }
```

Now, in a real life scenario, if you can potentially have big integers you should just use Long or BigInteger as suggested in other answers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Parse it as a `Long` and if it works parse it as an `Integer`, if it throws and Exception at that point, it overflows.

OR

Parse it as a `Long` and check if it is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 2):

You could parse it as a `BigInteger` and check if it's larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
BigInteger maxIntBigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
String str = "214748364781";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(str);
if (bi.compareTo(maxIntBigInteger) > 0) {
    System.out.println("Number is too big");
} else {
    int res = bi.intValue();
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8, you can parse it as type `Long` and then use `Math.toIntExact(long value)` to get the int value. This throws an unchecked `ArithmeticException` if there is an overflow.

Here is an example with your code:

```
String str = "214748364781";
int res = Math.toIntExact(Long.parseLong(str));
```

Or to simplify further:

```
int res = Math.toIntExact(Long.parseLong("214748364781"));
```

And as expected we get the integer overflow exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
    at java.lang.Math.toIntExact(Math.java:1011)
```